# How to print pattern output in Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with below data

*Table* : **emp**

| name |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| D |

*Expected Output* :

| names |
| --- |
| A |
| AB |
| ABC |
| ABCD |

I only know how to print data in horizontal form

```sql
SELECT LISTAGG(name,'|') 
  FROM emp;
```

Not sure how to cut the horizontal and get expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '|'), '|') AS names
FROM   ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS rn,
                name
         FROM   emp )
START WITH rn = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR rn + 1 = rn;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emp (name) AS
SELECT 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | NAMES |
> | --- |
> | A |
> | AB |
> | ABC |
> | ABCD |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=87bf15c72d96c7c1834628a99bca0848)*

Comment: can u explain what is happening in (REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, '|'), '|')) part ,i mean what is the output that is coming out from above line.

Comment: @wovef57249 [`SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH.html#GUID-D25A0F86-B559-4090-9164-7A2C84D1E11E). The output is generated by `SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH`; `REPLACE` just strips the delimiters that get added. You can see the difference if you remove the `REPLACE` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=72d145ef2b307af86f43d438a434a579).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'A' from dual union all
  3     select 'B' from dual union all
  4     select 'C' from dual union all
  5     select 'D' from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    (select listagg(col) within group (order by col) val,
  9            count(*) cnt
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select substr(val, 1, level) result
 13  from temp
 14  connect by level <= cnt;

RESULT
----------
A
AB
ABC
ABCD

SQL>
```

Basically, in `temp` CTE aggregate column values (and find number of rows), and then fetch substring in a hierarchical query which has as many levels as there are rows in the table.

Comment: It's confusing for me when you use CTE which query do i need to run from above

Comment: Sample data is in lines #1 - 6. Therefore, query begins at line #7; just precede it with the WITH keyword, i.e. `with temp as ...`